# Add elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to sum the elements of a list up?

The code below returns:  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```py
def main():
  total=0
  V=input("Input a list : ").split(",")
  print(type(V))
  total=sum(V)
  print(V)
```

Comment: What does `print(type(V[0]))` tell you? That's the type of item in your list.

Comment: you need to convert the items in `V` into `int` objects, currently, they are `str` objects. You *could* just do `total = sum(map(int, V))`

Answer (score 0):

If the user is supposed to enter a list of numbers, then you should convert them to ints, since it's originally a list of strings:

```py
total = sum(int(x) for x in V)
```

If you want to concatenate the strings into one, then use `join`:

```py
total = "".join(V)
```

(although I doubt this is what you want to do)